# Convert json string value to number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON string that reads:

```
[{
    "id": "id2",
    "index": "2",
    "str": "str2",
    "cent": "200",
    "triplet": "222"
},
{
    "id": "id3",
    "index": "3",
    "str": "str3",
    "cent": "300",
    "triplet": "333"
},
{
    "id": "id4",
    "index": "4",
    "str": "str4",
    "cent": "400",
    "triplet": "444"
},
{
    "id": "id5",
    "index": "5",
    "str": "str5",
    "cent": "500",
    "triplet": "555"
}]
```

The key-value pairs come dynamically from the server and I won't know beforehand what data to expect. 
For a charting library that I use, I need the values in JSON to be numeric rather than string viz. `"index":2` instead of `"index":"2"`
I am required to do this manipulation client-side using pure JS or jQuery.

This was my approach but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var temp = //some json that I receive
var jsonForChart = jQuery.extend(true, {}, temp);
$.each(temp, function(key, value) {
    $.each(value, function(k, v) {
        if(!isNaN(v)){
            jsonForChart[key][k] = Number(v);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what seems to be the problem? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/hbuc2knj/) (where `objects` is an Array of objects):

JavaScript

```
for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
    var obj = objects[i];
    for(var prop in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj[prop] !== null && !isNaN(obj[prop])){
            obj[prop] = +obj[prop];   
        }
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(objects, null, 2));
```

The last line will print out this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "index": 2,
    "str": "str2",
    "cent": 200,
    "triplet": 222
  },
  {
    "id": "id3",
    "index": 3,
    "str": "str3",
    "cent": 300,
    "triplet": 333
  },
  {
    "id": "id4",
    "index": 4,
    "str": "str4",
    "cent": 400,
    "triplet": 444
  },
  {
    "id": "id5",
    "index": 5,
    "str": "str5",
    "cent": 500,
    "triplet": 555
  }
]
```

Comment: This converts null to 0. I just spent 2 hours on a bug caused by this.

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron Fixed.

Comment: Yeah this works. But Can this go a little deeper. If one of the property is object then this code should even go into that obj and convert values. Kind of recurcively.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to check if the value is a number:

```js
var temp = [{
  "id": "id2",
  "index": "2",
  "str": "str2",
  "cent": "200",
  "triplet": "222"
}, {
  "id": "id3",
  "index": "3",
  "str": "str3",
  "cent": "300",
  "triplet": "333"
}, {
  "id": "id4",
  "index": "4",
  "str": "str4",
  "cent": "400",
  "triplet": "444"
}, {
  "id": "id5",
  "index": "5",
  "str": "str5",
  "cent": "500",
  "triplet": "555"
}];

var jsonForChart = jQuery.extend(true, {}, temp);
$.each(temp, function(key, value) {
  $.each(value, function(k, v) {
    // if the value can be parsed to int, it will be OR the value remains untouched
    jsonForChart[key][k] = +v || jsonForChart[key][k];
  });
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(jsonForChart, null, 3) + "</pre>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You get one big object but it's what you expect seeing the line `var jsonForChart = jQuery.extend(true, {}, temp);`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I haven't tested it but should work.

```
var temp = //some json that I receive
var jsonForChart = jQuery.extend(true, {}, temp);
$.each(temp, function(key, value) {
    $.each(value, function(k, v) {
        if(!isNaN(parseInt(v))){
            jsonForChart[key][k] = parseInt(v);
        }else{
            jsonForChart[key][k] = v;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't make much of a difference with that `else` condition. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// Iterate thorugh the array
[].forEach.call(x, function(inst, i){
    // Iterate through all the keys
    [].forEach.call(Object.keys(inst), function(y){
        // Check if string is Numerical string
        if(!isNaN(x[i][y]))
            //Convert to numerical value
            x[i][y] = +x[i][y];
    });

});

console.log(x);
```

[Live FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twuegudn/2/)

Comment: Works correctly for the conversion; somehow not getting the desired result with the charts.