# How to remove double quotes from json array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a array :

```
Var array=[{"name":"May","data1":"1121.0"}]
```

I want to change it to :

```
Var array= [{"name":"May","data1":1121.0}]
```

Comment: Please read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: So do you know what fields are numbers? If yes, than loop over and convert them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check using `Number.isNaN` with an attempted cast to a number using the `+` operator. If it returns true then do nothing. If it's false then change the value of the parameter to a cast number.

```js
var array=[{"name":"May","data1":"1121.0"}];
array.forEach(data => {
 for(let key in data) Number.isNaN(+data[key]) || (data[key] = +data[key])
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34014342/convert-json-string-value-to-number)

I'll summarize;

```
for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
    var obj = objects[i];
    for(var prop in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj[prop] !== null && !isNaN(obj[prop])){
            obj[prop] = +obj[prop];   
        }
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(objects, null, 2));
```

This does have a bug where 0 becomes null.

Comment: `"0"` cast to a number through the addition operator doesn't become null. Also, I don't think it's necessary to use `hasOwnProperty` - it's JSON. It's not inheriting from anything.

Comment: @zfrisch [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Either it is JSON (i.e. a string) or an object.

Comment: @str you're right,100% a misnomer on my part, but still kind of validates what I was saying.

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert the value mapped to the `"data1"` key to be a `number` instead of a `string`.

There are many ways to accomplish this in JavaScript, but the best way to do so would be to use `Number.parseFloat` like so:

```
var array = [{"name":"May","data1":"1121.0"}];
array[0]["data1"] = Number.parseFloat(array[0]["data1"]);

console.log(array[0]["data1"]); // 1121
```

If you need to perform this action with multiple objects inside of `array`, you could do

```
var array = [{"name":"May","data1":"1121.0"}, {"name":"May","data1":"1532.0"}, etc.] // Note that this is not valid JavaScript
array.map(obj => {obj["data1"] = Number.parseFloat(obj["data1"]); return obj;});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you only want to convert the value of `data1`, from `"1121.0"` to `1121.0`, in other words from **string** to **number**.

To convert only that key (data1), you only need this:

```
array[0].data1 = parseFloat(array[0].data1)
```

If that's not what you want, please explain better your question